# Why does logging a function expression execute the function with out invocation?

Tags: javascript, invocation

This function

```
function mapForEach(arr, fn) {

  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(
      fn(arr[i])
    )
  };

  return newArr;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
```

is invoked by

```
mapForEach(arr1, function (item) {
  return item * 2;
}); // [2,4,6]
```

and is not invoked by this variable declaration

```
var arr2 = mapForEach(arr1, function (item) {
  return item * 2;
});
```

yet is invoked when logged to the console

```
console.log(arr2); // [2,4,6] in the console
```

why isn't invocation here necessary?

```
console.log(arr2());
```

I'm still not clear how this differs from

```
function foo () { return 2 === 2 };
```

logs function definition

```
console.log(foo); // function foo() { return 2 === 2 }
```

invoked in log function, logs return value

```
console.log(foo()); // true
```

Comment: Because it *is* invoked by that variable declaration. Why do you think otherwise? You're just assigning the result to the name `arr2`. If you thought you were assigning a function, why did you name it an array?

Comment: I did not name it, I'm reading it and trying to learn, a process which has to happen unless you are born with perfect knowledge of Javascript (I wasn't).  I thought that the assignment of the return value does not exist in memory until execution which had to happen now after the declaration as arr2() which then synchronously would be available down line in the execution of the program.  So I was expecting console.log(arr2) to log a function definition.  Luckily we have things like stack overflow where we can ask questions we don't already have the answers to, as opposed to questions we do...?

Comment: It does not help you to be snarky. The question "why do you think otherwise" is exploratory, to identify where your misconceptions lie, so we can address them directly, instead of just pointing you to read a book (which should address *all* of your misconceptions, whatever they are, but is also almost uselessly general for a specific issue you are having).

Comment: I wasn't replying to _"Why do you think otherwise"_ but _"If you thought you were assigning a function, why did you name it an array?"_  Why assume I named it? If I had named it, and by naming it as 'array' implied  that I knew the answer to my question, why would I ask my question?  I don't mean to be snarky, I've just seen so many people get bashed here for asking questions. Isn't that what it's for? When i can differentiate a legitimate question from an illegitimate question or a question appropriate for a book to answer from one for a person to answer, I'll do so.

Comment: You did name it `var arr2 = ...`, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is just a slight confusion over the behaviour in the JavaScript console or in the return value from a `var` declaration.

The console will always display the value of the thing you type in. e.g. the return value of the call to a function. *However* the return value of a `var` is `undefined`. This means that while the `mapForEach` without an assignment will display `[2,4,6]` the function is indeed being called in both cases, it's just with `var arr2 =` the thing you were expecting is not displayed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027247/value-returned-by-the-assignment) for some more background on the return value from a `var` declaration.

Comment: Slight correction: "the return value of an assignment is `undefined`" is not true (`arr2 = [2, 4, 6]` evaluates to `[2, 4, 6]`); "the return value of a `var` statement is `undefined`" is closer to the truth (`var arr = [2, 4, 6]` evaluates to `undefined` in console, and cannot even be an lvalue in a program).

Comment: Many thanks @Amadan - I had a feeling my answer wasn't spot on given the contexts where the value of an assignment can be used, however was trying to explain based on the examples from the OP. Will update the answer to clarify!