# Why does executing a statement in browser console return `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Why does executing a statement like `var foo = 'bar'` in browser console returns `undefined`? Returning undefined from a function by default makes sense, but returning something when you execute a statement doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks for taking time to answer the question. Appreciate it!

Comment: because the statement did not return anything

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common feature in many languages. Variable declaration often returns undefined, see [Value returned by the assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027247/value-returned-by-the-assignment)

I might also add, lots of features in lots of languages make no sense ;) always check the docs