# Setting property on an empty object creates a string when used in .reduce()

Tags: javascript, typeerror, reduce

Here's the code in question:

```
Object.entries({
    orderStatus: null,
    orderType: null,
    limit: 25,
    offset: null,
    sortFields: null
}).reduce((acc, [a, b]) => b ? acc[a] = b : acc, {});
```

A console.log shows that the first time `acc[a]` is set, it just replaces `acc` with the string in `a`, then tries assign a property to `acc` (which is now a string) and throws the TypeError. When I use:

```
.reduce((acc, [a, b]) => b ? {...acc, ...{[a]: b}} : acc, {});
```

it works like a dream. Why would `acc[a]` be setting `acc` to 25 once it hits `limit`? shouldn't that be the same as `acc["limit"] = 25`?

Comment: Because `acc[a] = b` "returns" the content of `b` -> [12.4 Expression Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4)

Comment: [javascript - Value returned by the assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027247/value-returned-by-the-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function in `reduce` has to return the accumulated value.

In your conditional expression, you return the object in `acc` when `b` is falsey.

But when it's truthy, you return `acc[a] = b`. This returns the value that was assigned, i.e. `b`, not the value of `acc`.

A better way to write this would be with an ordinary `if`:

```
.reduce((acc, [a, b]) => { 
    if (b) {
        acc[a] = b;
    }
    return acc; }, {})
```

You could also use a comma expression to perform the assignment and then return the object separately:

```
.reduce((acc, [a, b]) => b ? (acc[a] = b, acc) : acc, {});
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!