# Array.reduce() in ES6, implicit returns and syntactic sugar. What is really happening?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am interested in understanding what is happening inside this algorithm. Let's consider the following dataset:

```
const data = [
  {
    emp_code: "a001",
    company_code: "company_a",
    name: "abx",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  },
  {
    emp_code: "b002",
    company_code: "company_b",
    name: "xbz ",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  },
  {
    emp_code: "a002",
    company_code: "company_a",
    name: "xbz ",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  },
  {
    emp_code: "b003",
    company_code: "company_b",
    name: "xbz ",
    details: [],
    details_dtypes: []
  }
];
```

Now, if I wanted to condense this data to an `object {}`, where each key is a unique `company_code` and its corresponding value is an `array []` of `emp_codes` for that company, I could do something like:

```
let result = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code];
  return r;
}, {});
```

In the above, we explicitly return the final object, which seems very clear.

Now, I've recently discovered that you can shorten this up with some syntactic sugar like so:

```
let result = data.reduce(
  (r, c) =>
    (r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]) && r,
  {}
);
```

The results are identical, but I'm not sure how that's possible. My understanding of `reduce()` is that there is an inner-loop that iterates over each item and allows you to apply certain logic to formulate your final result.
I see that they're using a `&&` operator. My hypothesis is that the logic between the parenthesis `()` executes like a traditional `reduce()` method and when complete, we simply return the result, hence `&& r`.

But something about that just seems wrong. Is the inner-loop still happening? If it is how are they able to isolate it like that without simply executing the condition after the first iteration, thus by returning `r`. Are they returning `r` for each iteration of the loop?

Here's a sandbox that shows both algorithms working: https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-with-reduce-nested-data-goee1. Many thanks to your contributions :)

Comment: Both the code are identical, in the second code, for each unique company_code you are adding all the emp_code and returning the object r.

Comment: When executing something like `foo && bar`, the last value to be interpreted is returned.

Comment: some folks use comma for this: `reduce (acc, x) => do_stuff, acc`, so that the accumulator is returned in any case.

Comment: @georg with `,` you need brackets around the body `(acc, x) => (do_stuff, acc)`, or `, acc` will be interpreted as a second argument to `reduce`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `&&`, if all expressions involved are truthy, it evaluates to the value of the final expression - the one that comes after the `&&`. So, if you have code like:

```
function foo() {
  <some expression>;
  return bar;
}
```

you could also write it like

```
function foo() {
  return <some expression> && bar;
}
```

or, with the implicit return of an arrow function:

```
const foo = () => <some expression> && bar;
```

which is equivalent to

```
const foo = () => {
  <some expression>;
  return bar;
};
```

So yes, for your code, with `&& r` at the end of the arrow function, that means that `r` is being implicitly returned on every iteration.

All that said, this is pretty much the *opposite* of syntactic sugar. This is the sort of thing you would often see if you run the code through a *minifier*, whose goal is to reduce amount of text in the Javascript as much as possible. But minified code is often very hard to read, and this is no exception, as your question shows. If using implicit `return` requires the comma operator or exploiting `&&` as evaluating to something *other* than a boolean, the code is probably too confusing to read easily, and explicit `return` is probably the better choice.

You could also consider pushing to an existing array in the accumulator object, thereby avoiding having to create many unnecessary intermediate arrays which only get spreaded later:

```
let result = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  if (!r[c.company_code]) {
    r[c.company_code] = [];
  }
  r[c.company_code].push(c.emp_code);
  return r;
}, {});
```

That's the code I would prefer. It's somewhat longer, but it's a *lot* easier to read when every statement/logical branch is on its own line.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured was happening in the 2nd code-block, I don't know why a user would choose to repeatedly return the accumulator after each iteration. Seems like it would have subpar performance compared to just returning the final result at the end. I was just stunned to see why the 2nd block is even a thing, maybe I'm not seeing the benefit of doing that other than having less code.

Comment: *" I don't know why a user would choose to repeatedly return the accumulator after each iteration."* because that's how `reduce` works. the return value from the first iteration is the value passed as accumulator for the second iteration, and so on. If you don't return a value in the first iteration you have `undefined` as accumulator in the second one.

Comment: The whole thing is an abuse of `reduce` anyway. It's just used for its side effect of iterating over an array. You could write the same code using `filter` or `map` or `forEach`.

Comment: @melpomene Using `.reduce` like this allows you to construct an object within a single block without any external mutation outside of that `.reduce` block, which some might argue is a point in its favor. It's not pure currently, though it could be made so if one *really* wanted to. I guess it's opinion-based

Comment: @melpomene not really, doing this using some other way to iterate the values will require an outside variable, with `reduce`, everything is contained.

Comment: @Titus `result` already is an outside variable. Now you have both `r` and `result`. Why not just use `result` everywhere?

Comment: @Thomas, I see now. my misunderstanding stems from the idea that the `return` line is executed at the end of the entire loop. Which now that I think about it, just seems kind of silly. I mean of course the acc should return after every iteration.  I've been using reduce() wrong this whole-time lol.

Comment: @melpomene That is just for storing the result not for generating it, with `reduce` `result` can be declared as a `const` (will not be mutated).

Comment: @Titus Keep in mind that `const` just prevents reassignment, not mutation. One could do `const result = {}; data.forEach( < mutate result > )`. Less external mutation just *looks* more elegant, IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, that is right, I should have said *and will not be mutated*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's disassemble this line:

```
(r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]) && r
```

Assignment in JS [always return assigned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027247/value-returned-by-the-assignment), and logical AND operator (`&&`) follows rules:

```
expr1 && expr2
```

If expr1 can be converted to true, returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`.

So basically it's same as

```
if(r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code])
  return r
```

And since arrays (`[...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]`) in JS are converted to true when parsed to boolean (same as objects, functions and symbols by the way), it always return r.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is brevity. When you reduce your code too much, you loose readability. That's the issue. Lets reverse the process and make your code more traditional.

```
let result = data.reduce(
  (r, c) => (r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]) && r,
  {}
);
```

Line 1, 3 and 4 is fairly simple. Tricky part is line 2.

```
(r, c) => (r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]) && r,
```

This is equivalent to:

```js
function processData(accumulator, currentItem) {
  if ( accumulator[currentItem.compony_code] === undefined ) {
    accumulator[currentItem.compony_code] = [];
  }

  accumulator[currentItem.compony_code].push(currentItem.emp_code);
  return accumulator;
}
```

---

Now coming to your hypothesis, about `()`, its a hack that creates an expression and allows you to do non-expression (*assignment in this case*) tasks.