# Javascript - Cannot understand this line of code

Tags: javascript

```
var statusCodes = {};

statusCodes[exports.ACCEPTED = 202] = "Accepted";
```

what does the second line mean? More specifically, the part in the squared brackets.

Comment: It's just an assignment. Assignments return the value assigned, so it's equivalent to `exports.ACCEPTED = 202` and `statusCodes[202]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex things are made of multiple simple things.  Just look at it one operation at a time.

First this operation is performed:

```
exports.ACCEPTED = 202
```

Which sets `exports.ACCEPTED` to the value `202`, and the operation evaluates to the value `202`.  Then this operation is performed:

```
statusCodes[202] = "Accepted"
```

Which sets `statusCodes[202]` to the value `"Accepted"`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a shorter version for

```
var statusCodes = {};
exports.ACCEPTED = 202;
statusCodes[exports.ACCEPTED] = "Accepted";
```

Check this question to get the idea

[Value returned by the assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027247/value-returned-by-the-assignment)